# Parsing GIF application's extension blocks- how to find block size?

Tags: php, delphi, parsing, decode, gif

I am parsing a GIF 89a (yes, I need to) file and I am stuck on Application Extension blocks.

They have 13 byte header (including the beginning 21 FF 0B bytes) and then there is some data. How much data is there? How do I know know much to read?

**You can skip the section below if you know the answer and just tell me :)**

This [page](http://www.fileformat.info/format/gif/egff.htm) says:

> ApplicationData contains the information that is used by the software application. This field is structured in a series of sub-blocks identical to the data found in a Plain Text Extension block."
>
> Each sub-block begins with a byte that indicates the number of data bytes that follow. From 1 to 255 data bytes may follow this byte. There may be any number of sub-blocks in this field.

This way I can parse NETSCAPE 2.0 blocks which are:

> 03 01 00 00 00

so I have a loop in PHP:

```
for (;;)
{
  $size = ord(fread($handle, 1));
  if ($size == 0) break;
  fseek($handle, $size);
}
```

or the same in Delphi, if you prefer:

```
while F.Position < F.Size do begin
    F.Read(Size, 1);            // F is TFileStream
    if Size = 0 then break;
    F.Position := F.Position + Size;
  end;
```

The iteration goes:

> size = read 1 byte; //size = 3;
>
> read 3 byte;
>
> size = read 1 byte;
>
> size = 0 so break

**So far, so good, here comes the problem: the XMP Data**

So the bytes in this block go like this (ASCII below):

> 21 FF 0B 58 4D 50 20 44 61 74 61 58 4D 50
>
> !`.XMP DataXMP

and then goes ASCII XML dump:

```
<?xpacket begin="ď»ż" id="W5M0MpCehiHzreSzNTczkc9d"?>
```

for about 500 bytes.

I obviously can't read it the same way I read NETSCAPE 2.0 blocks.
It seems to be terminated with 00 byte.
Should it just always read until 00 byte? Then if would fail on NETSCAPE 2.0 blocks!

**How should a GIF decoder behave on Application Extension blocks? How much data is in them?**

[Problematic XMP Data image](http://imgur.com/7VWjYhM)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok- the NETSCAPE 2.0 block approach might be fine and it was failing on the XML because my file could be corruptly read.

Comment: I came about the same issue. So it's not a corrupted file. The XMP section seems to be confusing since it doesn't seem to follow the sub-block pattern. However that's on purpose. The XMP section has a magic trailer of 258 bytes. No matter where you jump into that section you will always end up at the terminating block. For more information see the "XMP specification part 3".

Comment: @Bunny83 Thanks a lot!